# /tmp/mysql.sock keeps disappearing

Tags: command-line, server, mysql

I have a clean install of Ubuntu server 14.04, and installed MySQL as part of the install.  An application I run on this server requires there to be a socket at /tmp/mysql.sock . It's not there.  I found that it's being placed in /run/mysqld.sock

Executing "ln -s /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock" fixes the problem, but the symlink goes away with each reboot.

I've tried editing /etc/mysql/my.conf by changing the socket location in each place (there are three - in the [client] block, in the [mysqld_safe] block, and in the [mysqld] block) but that didn't seem to fix it.

How do I make the socket persist in the right place?  I suppose I can create an init.d script that runs the ln command each time, but that seems awfully kludgy.

Any advice much appreciated.  Please use small words, as I'm kind of a newbie to all this.

Note:  This is a server install, please limit advice to command-line.

Comment: *"changing the socket location in each place"* you changed it **to** `/tmp/mysql.sock` in the config, with MySQL shut down and then restarted MySQL and that *didn't* fix it?

Comment: Hmmm, MySQL was not shutdown at the time.  Maybe that messed with it.  Will try again.

Comment: Yup, the problem was stopping the mysql service.  All working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, above, the problem was my failing to stop the mysql service while doing this.  Thanks!